# Calculate payback

Tags: php

I want to know if there is a better way to do this function. The function calculates a payback. Basically, the company spend x amount of money and per year they will save some money overtime. They want to count how many years it takes to get the money back.

I.E. The company spends 100k. year 1 they save 45k, year 2 save 45k and year 3 save 45k for this investment; therefore, they will get the money back in around 2.22 years.

I created a function which works ok, but there is something that tells me is not right. I cannot figure out what is that. It takes 2 parameters:

- Array: each year how much the company saves. In the previous example would be something like [45000, 45000, 45000].
  Target: Total of money spend. 100k in the previous example

```php
// this is a modified version of the previous code that was broken.

$years = [1000.00, 2000.00, 3000.00, 4000.00, 5000.00];
$expected = 7500.00;

function payback($array, $target)
{
    $total = 0 - $target;

    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
    {          
        $total += $array[$i];

        if($total <= 0)
        {
            $previous = $total;

        } 
        if($total > 0)
        {
            echo "Previous: " . $previous;
            echo "\nArray: " . $array[$i];
            $ytd = abs($previous / $array[$i]);
            $count = $i;
            break;
        }

    }
    return round($ytd + $count, 2) ;
}

echo "payback is: " . payback($years, $expected);
```

Comment: Your code lacks automatic unit tests. Some for simple cases and some for more complex ones. Using these tests you can find out where your code is broken.

Comment: I see... when i enter different numbers is where the problem was starting. I modified the code and it should be working now. Thank you @mickmackusa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with all that mickmackusa has said, but I have four additions:

- The return value must be defined for cases where the values in the yearly array add up to less than the total value that was spent. I chose to return `false` for this. So when the function return `false` it means that it cannot compute the payback years, given the input.
- When the total value that was spent exactly matched the total sum of the array (15,000), the function of mickmackusa will return nothing. That's because of the `if ($newTarget < 0)`, this should be `if ($newTarget <= 0)`.
- The names chosen are not the best possible. What information does `$array` or `$target` contain? The first name is chosen based on the type of the variable, and the second seems to be based on what the function needs to do. I've always learned that a variable name should reflect the meaning of the data it contains. The names I use in the code below might be a bit more verbose than the old ones, but they tell you clearly what they contain. Correctly chosen variable names help you to understand your own code, especially if you look at it again after a few years.
- I've done the same thing with the algorithm inside the function. The function of mickmackusa works, but it is not the easiest to read or understand. A `$newTarget` is created and later replaces the original `$target`. So the target changes? Well, yes, it does. In the end this is not a complicated function, and it is understandable, but by using better names the algorithm can better explain itself. I use a variable called `$totalSaved` that keeps track of what was saved in total.

This is new code:

```
<?php

$savingsPerYear = [1000.00, 2000.00, 3000.00, 4000.00, 5000.00];
$totalSpent     = 7500.00;

function getPaybackYears($totalSpent, $savingsPerYear) {
    $totalSaved = 0.00;
    foreach ($savingsPerYear as $yearNo => $savedThisYear) {
        $totalSaved += $savedThisYear;
        if ($totalSaved >= $totalSpent) {
            $spendingLeftThisYear = $totalSpent - ($totalSaved - $savedThisYear);
            return round($yearNo + $spendingLeftThisYear / $savedThisYear, 2);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$payback = getPaybackYears($totalSpent, $savingsPerYear);

if ($payback === false) echo "payback not reached";
                   else echo "payback in years: " . $payback;

?>
```

**In summary:** I've corrected two bugs and improved readability.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be calling `sizeof()` after every iteration.  In fact, using `foreach()` eliminates the need to count at all and provides an incrementing counter variable.

When you want to break out of a loop and immediately return from your custom function, just use `return`.

Notice in my code below that it is not necessary to write an `elseif` or `else` condition.

You can avoid working with negative values and calling `abs()` by using subtraction instead of adding to the negative initial value.

I also, try to keep the number of declared variables to a minimum.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CAVsk))

```
$years = [1000.00, 2000.00, 3000.00, 4000.00, 5000.00];
$expected = 7500.00;

function payback($array, $target) {
    foreach ($array as $i => $amount) {
        $newTarget = $target - $amount;
        if ($newTarget < 0) {
            return round($i + ($target / $amount), 2);
        }
        $target = $newTarget;
    }
}

echo "payback is: " . payback($years, $expected);
```

Output:

```
payback is: 3.38
```